# Relation between integrals ${\bf Re}\int fd\mu$ and $\int{\bf Re} (f) d\mu$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:X\to \Bbb C$ be a complex integrable function and $\mu$ a complex measure on $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$. Is there any relation between $\displaystyle{\bf Re}\int fd\mu$ and $\displaystyle\int{\bf Re} (f) d\mu$ or $\displaystyle\int{\bf Re} (f) d|\mu|$?

Answer (score 2):

Always 
$$\displaystyle{\bf Re}\int fd\mu=\int{\bf Re} (f) d\mu$$

Comment: Also when $\mu$ is a complex measure?

Comment: @niki Yes: this follows directly by the definition.